# How to add parameters in the comments of a method in Visual Studio after it has been generated?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have comments such as:

```
/// <summary>
///     Creates a filename given the end date provided
/// </summary
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetFileName(DateTime date, string filePath) {
        var ret = string.Format("file_{0}[{1}].txt", date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), date.ToString("HHmm"));
        return Path.Combine(filePath, ret);
    }
```

Visual studio automatically created the comments above when I typed ///.

Is there away to re-generate the above comments and add in the Parameters, which I've newly added recently?

I know I can delete and redo it by typing /// and it will automatically generate with the proper parameters. Is there a a different way?

Comment: ReSharper will do this for you, not sure about VS.

Answer (score 1):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is a Visual Studio extension that could help out with generating these types of documentation.

I've also heard good things about [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), but haven't personally used it.

Otherwise, I usually just retype the /// if it ever changes.

Answer (score 1):

*First*, you can do it manually by adding necessary `<param>` items to your summary.

```
/// <summary>
///     Creates a filename given the end date provided
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">It is a date</param>
/// <param name="filePath">Valid path</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetFileName(DateTime date, string filePath) {
   var ret = string.Format("file_{0}[{1}].txt", date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), date.ToString("HHmm"));
    return Path.Combine(filePath, ret);
}
```

*Second* (for lazy people), you can remove this comment and type "///" again :)

Comment: I assume OP is already aware of the syntax, I think they're looking for a way to do it quicker via the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

GhostDoc is the tool to go for as also suggested by TheMi7ch. You can download it using Visual Studio Extension and Updates under Tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense works pretty well for me:

1. Go to the end of the `</summary>` line and hit enter - VS will generate a new line with `///` on it already.
2. Type `<p` and Intellisense should give you some pretty good suggestions.

On some setups I've seen Intellisense simply list all the missing `param` tags, and you can just add them one by one this way. On other setups it will only give you `<param name=""></param>` and place the insertion point between the quotes for you fill in the parameter name. I'm guessing which behavior you get depends on whether you have Resharper installed.